# Trigger a second jQuery dialog from an initial jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I have an issue trying to trigger a second jQuery dialog widget from an initial dialog widget.

The first jQuery UI dialog contains three  tags in a list.  Clicking on one of the links needs to trigger one of three different HTML forms in a second jQuery UI dialog, and dismiss the first dialog.

I have no idea how to go about setting this up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// Code for First Dialog

```
$( "#first-dialog" ).dialog({
    height: 500,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
```

//Code for Second Dialog

```
$( "#second-dialog" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
```

//Code to open the second-dialog  and close of first-dailog

```
$("#li").click(function() {
    $( "#second-dialog" ).dialog('open');
    $( "#first-dialog" ).dialog('close');
         });
```

and give the form-html what ever you need in second-dialog html.